# Flower ETL status success but result is false

Tags: etl, celery-task, flower

Need help with Open Semantic Search Server Edition. I cannot upload and index any files from a folder to make it visible in search engine. Direct Import/upload for excel file is working though. I though it is just a syntax problem but I tried a few path notation and it is still the same. Please help.
[Flower Result False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRqg1.jpg)